# C# class generated from the proto file using custom tool ProtBufTool does not have the parseFrom and mergeFrom methods

Tags: c#-4.0, protocol-buffers

I using the custom tool 'ProtoBufTool' in Visual studio to generate the C# class files from the .proto files. However, the generated output class does not have the parseFrom and the mergeFrom methods. Am I missing providing some option or something in the proto file or in the tool settings? I did not find anything online that would give me any clues to solve this. Also, apart from the messages, my proto file just has option *optimize_for = SPEED;* at the beginning of the file. I don't have any build action on the proto file.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which tool / library are you using, ***exactly***?

Answer (score 0):

From the name of the tool, it sounds like you are using protobuf-net. That is just one of [several protobuf implementations](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) for c# / .net, but it is not a direct port and has a different API - instead it tried to be idiomatic .net **first**, and a serializer *second* (for example, you dont even need a .proto - you can use regular POCO types). For example, typical usage might be:

```
var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<YourType>(inputStream);
```

If you want an implementation with the same API as the java etc implementations, then [protobuf-csharp-port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) may be more to your liking. This is a more direct port of the java API.

Comment: Yes, it is protobuf-net. Makes more sense now. Since we are porting our code from Java, I guess I will go the protobuf-csharp-port route. Thanks for the response Marc.